# ¿Cómo conseguir referencias de miebros de una clase en C#?

Tags: c#, class, puntero-a-miembro

Tengo varias clases y necesito acceder a ciertos miembros de la clase príncipal y poder modificarlos en las secundarias. Para simplificar el código dentro de las clases secundarias he heho una clase base que es común a todas.

```
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public class Velocidad
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public class BasePrincipal
{
    public Velocidad velocidad;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------  
public class BaseSecundaria : BasePrincipal
{
    public Humano humano;
    public BaseSecundaria(Humano humano)
    {
        //lectura y escritura
        this.humano = humano;//Aquí si se copia la dirección de la memoria(es un puntero) 

        //solo lectura 
        this.velocidad = humano.velocidad;   //Mi intención era copiar la dirección de la memoria también, pero esto no ocurre
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------

public class Correr : BaseSecundaria
{
    public Correr(Humano humano) : base(humano)
    {
        velocidad.x = 10f;         //NO hay cambios en el objeto principal                      
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------    
public class Saltar : BaseSecundaria
{
    public Saltar(Humano humano) : base(humano)
    {
        humano.velocidad.y = 10f;  //SI hay cambios en el objeto principal
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------    
public class Humano : BasePrincipal
{
    Correr correr;
    Saltar saltar;

    public Humano()
    {
        velocidad = new Velocidad();

        correr = new Correr(this);
        saltar = new Saltar(this);

                                       //salida en la consola
        Console.WriteLine(velocidad.x);// impirime 10
        Console.WriteLine(velocidad.y);// impirime 10  

    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Humano humano = new Humano();
    }
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Y la pregunta es si se puede referenciar los miembros de la clase "BasePrincipal" y en caso que se pueda.. ¿cómo se hace?

En C y C++ sería algo tan simple como añadir un asterisco:

```
public class BasePrincipal
{    
    public Velocidad *velocidad; //lectura y escritura 
}
```

compilar asi:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe ejemplo.cs

Pero en C# esto parece que es una odisea...
Como dije la finalidad de todo esto es simplificar el código y ahorar memoria.

Gracias!!

Comment: No tenes que hacer nada raro.. probaste a escribir el nombre de la variable? si pones velocidad dentro de un metodo, deberia reconocerlo sin problemas...

Comment: Igual toda tu estructura de clases no tiene sentido.. Saltar no es una clase.. es un metodo de Humano? toda la estructura de clases es rarisima y bastante sin sentido...

Comment: Si pero los cambios que haga en esa variable no se ven reflejados en la clase principal (Humano), a eso me refiero...

Comment: Si, un pequeño despiste... ahora lo areglo... la clase Humano debe tener como base  "BasePrincipal" i'm sorry...

Comment: Si si, saltar y correr son clases... y tienen métodos que hacen saltar y correr al humano... solo que aquí está simplificado al máximo para solo reflejar lo que es el problema en si y no liar mas de la cuenta a la gente que lo lea.

Comment: Me parece que tenes una confusion enorme.. en que clase no se ven los cambios? en la clase humano que pasas si se ven los cambios.. vos en cual queres que se vean?

Comment: Si, en la clase Humano, ahí deben verse reflejados los cambios... de hecho así lo tengo hecho y funciona bien... pero quiero usar punteros o algo similar para simplificar el código y ahorrar memoria. Es decir, usar (velocidad.x) en vez de (humano.velocidad.x) haria mas legible mi código... además si todas las clases manejan el mismo puntero estaría ahorrando memoria ya que ahorraría instanciar esas variables por tripicado.

Comment: Ok, ya corregí los fallos... la verdad es que si era un disparate... I'm sorry... ya está todo bien!!!

Comment: Esto es c#... las variables son punteros... no los armas a mano ni los pasas.. se pasan automaticamente... y los nombres de las clases se simplifican al pasar por jit...

Comment: Jit? Que es Jit?... Si las variables fuesen punteros al modificar el valor de this.velocidad vería los cambios en la clase Humano y eso no es lo que ocurre (es por eso que hice esta pregunta).

Comment: En donde? Creo que estas confundiendo entre clase e instancia... this es la clase en la cual estas parado... que tendra que ver con humano? Jit es el compilador just in time... creo que deberias probar con [mcve] asi entendemos que no se te actualiza.... yo no entiendo que pensas que no actualiza... parece solo un error de concepto

Comment: Si tienes razón, estoy confundiendo el concepto entre clase e instancia... estoy un poco verde aún con la programación... (me informaré sobre eso del jit)... en cuanto a lo del ejemplo mínimo de eso si estoy totalmente seguro de lo que estoy hablando. con "this.velocidad" no se ven los cambios en" Humano" y con "humano.velocidad" si se ven... el código que escribí ahí arriba debería servir perfectamente como ejemplo mínimo... de hecho voy a poner un que se imprima el valor por pantalla y creo que asi estaria completo....estoy usando Unity no sé si haria falta una función Main() o algo asi...

Comment: This.velocidad es una instancia de la clase en la que estas parado, que si es saltas es la clase saltar... no la vlase humano. Que herede de humano no quiere decir que va a modificar la clase humano, que es otra instancia distinta... son dos clases distintas.. son dos variables distintas.. son dosninstancias distintas de clases distintas... this simboliza la instancia donde estas parado. La herencia es de clase, no de instancia de clase...

Comment: En cuanto pueda te escribo una respuesta completa pero estas mirando cosas distintas...

Comment: Si si, eso del puntero "this" si lo comprendo, sé como funciona...  pero al hacer esto (this.velocidad = humano.velocidad;) en el constructor mi intención era que se copiara la dirección de la memoria y asi que las dos instancias de clase manejaran el mismo segmento de memoria... pero eso no ocurre... lo que se copia es el valor.... Lo que yo veo es que "humano.velocidad" si funciona como un puntero pero "this.velocidad"   no lo hace. ... Ok, esperaré no tengas prisa!! Muchas Gracias!! :-)

Comment: Que sentido tiene tu nueva edicion a la pregunta?

Comment: La hize antes de que tu me contestaras... cuando aún creía que estaba pasando lo que yo decia.... Este código de C# es el primero que compilo fuera de Unity... Ahi queda hasta que aberigüe que demonios está pasandome y luego probablemente lo vuelva a editar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes un lio de cosas..

Aca hay un problema que no estas explicando.. si estas copiando referencias porque son clases.. el problema es.. que estas mostrando?

mira por ejemplo aca:

```
velocidad.x = 10f;         //NO hay cambios en el objeto principal
```

Y no, no va a haber cambios en el objeto principal, que no se cual seria, porque esto, es otra clase! es otra instacia, es otra cosa totalmente diferente.

```
humano.velocidad.y = 10f;  //SI hay cambios en el objeto principal
```

Y si hay cambios.. sobre el objeto humano ese que trajiste como parametro.. que puede o no ser el mismo que vos pensas que estas cambiando. Eso, es otro objeto totalmente diferente.

Creo que tenes confundido lo que hace la herencia. La herencia, es de clase. Lo que hace el compilador, es crear una super clase nueva, que incluye a la clase que se hereda y lo que agregues nuevo.

Ahora, cuando vos instancias clases, ya sea con herencia o sin ella, son todas distintas!

Tratando de guiarme por tu ejemplo, para llamar a la clase Saltar, tuviste que hacer:

```
Saltar s = new Saltar();
```

Y luego llamaste al metodo Saltar:

```
Humano h = new Humano();
s.Saltar(h);
```

Esa h ahi arriba, no es la misma variable humano que esta dentro de la clase Saltar.. es otra instancia que nada que ver... entonces lo que vos hagas en Saltar, esta en otro mundo.. es mas, la clase saltar, con toda su herencia, no tiene definido humano en ese punto.

Para ejemplificar esto, vamos a hacer que tire un error de puntero nulo.

Cambia tu funcion Saltar por esto:

```
public Saltar(Humano humano) : base (humano)
{
    humano.velocidad.y = 10f;  //SI hay cambios en el objeto principal
    this.humano.velocidad = 1; //Va a tirar un lindo error en tiempo de ejecucion
}
```

Porque ese humano que esta dentro de saltar, viene de otra instancia de clase distinta al humano anterior.

Comment: Tal y como tu lo estás explicando si es cierto todo lo que dices. Pero yo no estoy haciendo eso... Yo estoy pasando como parametro al **constructor** de la clase Saltar el **puntero THIS**....  y cuando uso desde algún método de la instancia  "saltar" el miembro **this.humano** creeme cuando te digo que no son mundos diferentes. Todos los cambios salen al exterior y son permanentes. Pero por desgracia eso solamene ocurre con ese miembro. Con los demás miembros ocurre exactamente lo que tu acabas de explicar. Te agradezco enormemente que te hayas molestado en elaborar esa explicación. :-)

Comment: @IvánRodríguez como te dije, tu ejemplo esta incompleto, y por eso no puedo saber que te pasa exactamente, y estoy deduciendo cual es tu problema.  no se como le pasas this al constructor de una clase, y no se de que serviria eso... tampoco mostras en ningun lado, cual de todas las cosas estas mirando...

Comment: Es super simple. todas las clases tienen un miembro en común "velocidad" que se hereda de  "BasePrincipal". BaseSecundaria sive para instanciar el miembro "humano" que solo tendrán las clases "correr y "saltar". Al declarar las instacias correr y saltar dentro de la clase "humano" y pasarles el puntero "this" tengo acceso a la variavle velocidad que pertenece a la clase Humano, pero unicamente funciona como un puntero (lectura y escritura) si uso la variable humano instanciada por BaseSecundaria, en otro caso "velocidad" funciona como variable local. Y yo quiesiera que tambien fuera un puntero

Comment: @IvánRodríguez no se donde lo estas probando, pero yo veo 10 y 10 cuando lo ejecuto...

Comment: @IvánRodríguez miralo por vos mismo https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYILBy

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en el motor grafico de Unity. Si, acabo de compilarlo por separado yo también y también veo 10 y 10. Ahora si que no comprendo nada. Realmente está funcionando como a mi me gustaría (como punteros).  no comprendo porque con Unity no me sucede lo mismo. El problema debe ser otro! aunque realmente me alegro de que se pueda hacer lo que yo queria. Voy a tener que investigar a ver que demonios está pasando con Unity. No se sitendrá que ver algo con la función Main porque en Unity no se usa. Oye, te agradezco muchisimo que te hayas tomado tu tiempo en ayudarme.